# For what value of $k$ does system of Equations have infinitely many solutions? Gaussian Elimination - is my approach correct?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

$$ x + ky + z = 1$$
$$   -  y + z = 2$$
$$x + y + 2z = 3$$

Using Gaussian elimination I reduced the augmented matrix to:

[\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&3\\
0&-1&1&2\\
0&0&k-2&2k-4\\
\end{bmatrix}]

And so for k = 2 there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: How do you obtain the first and  last rows?

Answer (score 1):

The approach of using Gaussian elimination is for sure correct, but your equation system isn't the one represented by your reduced matrix, because:

1. The equation system has no solution for $k=1$, otherwise it has one
   unique solution.
2. The system represented by your reduced matrix has
   infinitely many solutions if $k=2$.

Comment: you are right, apologies, there is a typo in the system of equations... fixed now

Comment: Now, it's correct. Infinitely many folutions for $k=2$. I would have transformed it to this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2&3\\
0&-1&1&2\\
0&k-2&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, for $k \ne 2$, it must be $y=0$, $z=2$ and $x=-1$.